# How to install a dictionary (danish) in Texmaker

Tags: dictionaries

I began my physics studies last summer. All our written assignment is in LaTeX and that's ok - and I use Texmaker. I think Texmanker is a good program and I have just one problem with it. I can't install a danish spellcheck and use it in LaTeX. That is not nice, so I really need your help!

Help me please. Tell me where and how to install a danish spellcheck and how to use it in Texmaker, pls. I am desperate! :/

Comment: A late post, but I found it useful, look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204505/spelling-check-for-texmaker) for those who keep looking in this direction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Step one is to download a dictionary, if you haven't done that already. The dictionaries are the same kind used by LibreOffice, OpenOffice and others, and can be downloaded from e.g. http://archive.services.openoffice.org/pub/mirror/OpenOffice.org/contrib/dictionaries/ The Danish one is *da_DK.zip*.

After downloading, unzip the archive, and place it somewhere convenient. It doesn't really matter where you place the files, I think.

To activate the dictionary in Texmaker, go to Options --> Configure Texmaker, and look under the Editor page. In the middle there is a field called *Spelling dictionary*. Click the folder icon next to it (highlighted in screenshot) to browse for the files you just downloaded and unpacked. Among the downloaded files there is one called *da_DK.dic*, which is the one you want. Click OK, and you're done.

[image]

## Updated Dictionary Link

The new working link for acquiring Danish Language can be found on [Apache OpenOffice Extensions](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/en/project/dict-da). Just unpack the *.oxt* file as an ordinary ZIP file.

Comment: @user41306 Glad to hear it! Perhaps you could consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left. That will mark the question as answered (and award some reputation points to both yourself and me).

Comment: link is 404. http://wps-community.org/download/dicts this one worked

Answer (score 4):

Linux (Ubuntu) users must

1. [download the dictionary](http://archive.services.openoffice.org/pub/mirror/OpenOffice.org/contrib/dictionaries/) for English spelling check, download `en_GB` then unZIP it and copy it to along with complete path at `/user/share/texmaker/en_GB.dic`.
2. Go to Options --> Configure Texmaker --> Editor --> spelling dictionary and provide complete path where unzipped dictionary file with `.dic` extension is present. Now for spelling checking open your TeX file and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> you will see all word with spelling mistake would be underlined with red color.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I have `myspell-pt-br` installed, but the corresponding dictionaries don't appear on Texmaker (LO Writer is OK). What gives?

Comment: Nevermind. Thanks to the discussion at http://askubuntu.com/q/24749/48105, I found out what happened: I've installed `myspell-bt-br` but it wasn't showing at `/usr/share/myspell/dicts`. Turns out `pt_BR.dic` was at '/usr/share/hunspell`, even though there is no such package as `myspell-pt-br`. Go figure.

Comment: Your link is 404 now...

Comment: http://wps-community.org/download/dicts this is working one

Answer (score 2):

The links for downloading the dictionaries in the other answers don't seem to work anymore. But the required files may be on your package manager. For example, on ubuntu, you can install the dictionaries with the command (for greek):

```
sudo apt install myspell-el-gr
```

And then select the dictionary from

```
Options --> Configure Texmaker --> Editor --> Spelling dictionary
```