# Need help installing a Portuguese dictionary in TexMaker

Tags: texmaker, dictionaries

I've all ready tried to install this file `pt_BR.dic` in the TeXmaker, but when I went to pull the file through the TeXmaker configuration, it simply doesn't worked.
I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Is there any alternative form of installation for a Portuguese dictionary?

Comment: Related: [How to install a dictionary (danish) in Texmaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145862/how-to-install-a-dictionary-danish-in-texmaker)

Answer (score 0):

Download these two files:

[pt_BR.aff](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42709342/pt_BR.aff) and [pt_BR.dic](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42709342/pt_BR.dic)

and save them on TeXmaker folder. (I use TeXstudio, it is similar and its path is `/usr/share/texstudio`).

After, configure the editor to look for the files.