# Spelling check for Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, spelling, dictionaries

I have trouble spell checking my document in Texmaker. When I press spellcheck, I get the error `No dictionary Available`. I really read every thing to fix this problem but it is not clear for me especially about directory?

I am running Texmaker on Mac. 
My Texmaker is located in application, and my dictionary (Oxford Dictionary of English) is located  in application too.

spelling dictionary  in Texmaker as shown in this picture is

```
/Users/garry/Downloads/TexmakerMacosxLion/texmaker.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/en_GB.dic
```

[image]

Comment: Does that file actually exist?

Comment: You can open the directory for check the availability or existence of the dictionary over the icon at the right of the path you show us.

Answer (score 35):

I know this is a very late reply but I'm just writing this for someone else who might have the same problem. I am using Texmaker on Yosemite and had the same issue. This page solved it:

http://www.swisswuff.ch/wordpress/?p=166

In case it goes down, here are the steps:

> 1. Get the dictionary file en_US.oxt from Open Office [link](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/en_US-dict)
> 2. rename the file to en_US.zip.
> 3. Unzip it.
> 4. Copy both en_US.aff and en_US.dic to your default or preferred dictionary location.
> 5. Use Texmaker >Options > Configure Texmaker > Editor > Spelling dictionary to select en_US.dic as your preferred spelling dictionary.

Comment: Not sure why I need the .aff file as well, but this fixed the problem for me. +1

Answer (score 6):

Most often, the dictionary (en_US.dic and en_US.aff) will be located in >/ur/share/hunspell/

In Texmaker, In

> Options/Configure Texmaker/Editor/Spelling Dictionary

load the 'en_US.dic' file.

If it is not there, do as following:

Try this link to get the latest updated dictionary
http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/english-dictionaries-apache-openoffice

Download the .oxt file. Extract the files and then Open texmaker and in

> Options/Configure Texmaker/Editor/Spelling Dictionary

load the 'en_US.dic' file.

Comment: Welcome! This is for Linux boxes, but the question seems to deal with Mac OS X.

Answer (score 5):

I got the exact same problem. It seems the link to the dictionary is not being set correctly. In my case, the path to the dictionary is as follows

```
/Users/XXXX/Downloads/TexmakerMacosxLion/texmaker.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/en_GB.dic
```

But when I click on the browsing button, I get a list of dictionaries. Choose whatever you want and mark the `inline` option. This will set the correct path. In my case, I chose `en_GB.dic`.

[image]

The correct path is

```
/Applications/texmaker.app/Contents/Resources/en_GB.dic
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

On the terminal run the following command:

`sudo find . -name 'en_GB.dic'`

This should return all the paths where you have the Dic file.

[image]

Best case scenario, you will find the path of Texmaker or any other application which use such type of dictionaries (sublime in my case).

Copy and paste the path in Option -> Configure Texmaker -> editor -> Spelling dictionary.

[image]

Worst case scenario: you didn't find the Dic file.

Download the Dic file from the Texmaker official repository:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mercutiodesign/texmaker-3.3.3/master/dictionaries/en_GB.dic
```

Do the same for the downloaded file directory (add it to the Spelling dictionary in Texmaker options).

ENJOY MISTAKES FREE LATEX.